# Always prefer std::string(ptr, size) to std::string(first, last) if possible?

Tags: c++, string, performance, time-complexity, standards

Consider:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

string sv2s_1(string_view sv)
{
    return string(sv.data(), sv.size());
}

string sv2s_2(string_view sv)
{
    return string(sv.begin(), sv.end());
}
```

In `sv2s_1`, `string` needs to allocate the internal buffer at most once.

In `sv2s_2`, `string` doesn't know how large the internal buffer should be, so it must push back the characters one by one, and may reallocate and copy the internal buffer many times.

Provided that `first` and `last` are ***random access iterators***, `string(first, last)` can use `last - first` to fast get the size of its internal buffer, so the performance is equal to `string(ptr, size)`.

*Question:* If `first` **and** `last` are *random access iterators,*

**Does the C++ standard guarantee** `string(first, last)` **is equivalent to** `string(ptr, size)` **in terms of performance?**

Comment: I mean there is [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) so you don't need random access iterators. On the other hand, if you have a pointer and a size why shouldn't there be a random access iterator aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see such a requirement in the standard. The standard [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts) that `X(i, j)` constructs a sequence container equal to the range `[i, j)` and that the complexity of the expression is sequence dependent.

Looking into a particular implementation, `libstdc++` [precomputes](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc#L203) the range size for forward, bidirectional and random access iterators:

```
template<typename InIterator>
void basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc>::
_M_construct(InIterator beg, InIterator end, std::forward_iterator_tag) {
    // ...
    size_type dnew = static_cast<size_type>(std::distance(beg, end));
    // ...
}
```

Note that `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag` and `std::random_access_iterator_tag` [are derived](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) from `std::forward_iterator_tag`, and can be implicitly converted into it, so this `_M_construct` overload is called for  forward, bidirectional and random access iterators (and contiguous iterators in C++20).

Answer (score 2):

[std::basic_string's doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) guaranties complexity as linear for both following constructors:

```
constexpr basic_string( const CharT* s,
                        size_type count,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); // (4)

template< class InputIt >
constexpr basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); // (6)
```

Performance is not guaranty though, and neither should be implemented using the other one.

Note: constructor (6) taking iterators takes InputIterator, not RandomIterator (even if implementation might dispatch on iterator category).